# How to communicate with a BES?

Tags: c#, api, blackberry

I am trying to get a list of devices and their software from a BES. My first thought was to connect directly to the database and query it directly, but from what I can tell in a 'Hosted' Blackberry environment I would not have access to the database. Another option I can see is the Blackberry Administrator API.

Does anyone have any other suggestions on getting the list of installed software (from C#).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Blackberry Administrator API is, as described on the [overview page](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/adminapi.jsp), sure does allow access to the BES configuration database, but it can only be installed along with the other Blackberry Enterprise Server pieces (and not the Express version, by the way).

So if you're using a hosted BES service, chances are that they do *not* give you API access--but it wouldn't hurt to ask if it's available.

If you confirm with your host that they can give you access, you probably want to start with the [Fundamentals Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25821/index.jsp?name=Fundamentals+Guide+-+BlackBerry+Administration+API5.0.3&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Administration+API&subCategory=) and then the [Getting Started with .NET BES API guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25823/index.jsp?name=For+Microsoft+.NET+Developers+-+Getting+Started+Guide+-+BlackBerry+Administration+API5.0.3&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Administration+API&subCategory=). Later you can move on to the [more detailed .NET Development Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25825/index.jsp?name=For+Microsoft+.NET+developers+-+Development+Guide+-+BlackBerry+Administration+API5.0.3&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Administration+API&subCategory=) and the [full API reference](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/baa/5.0.3/). Good luck!